# Matploplib задает неверные расстояния между точками графика

Tags: python, matplotlib, график

Необходимо нарисовать график изменения температуры образца от времени. У меня есть таблица с замерами типа "31(секунда)  78(градусов)". Решил сделать график с помощью `matploplib` на `python`, но при построении графика библиотека не учитывает расстояние между точками. Получается так, что между точками `52` и `117` такое же расстояние на графике, как и между `3073` и `3074`. В итоге график похож на 2 прямые, что в корне неверно.
Не понимаю, как исправить это, прошу помощи у сообщества

Вот код:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = '0 52  117 207 375 820 1353    1380    1480    1528    1554    1576    1605    1637    1683    1703    1749    1817    1863    1943    2060    2214    2318    2549    2795    2480    2977    2980    2999    3016    3024    3030    3035    3046    3052    3058    3063    3068    3073    3074    3084    3089    3094    '
y1 = '80    100 120 140 160 180 190 192 194 196 198 200 202 204 206 208 210 212 214 216 218 220 222 224 226 224 222 220 218 216 214 212 210 208 206 204 202 200 198 196 194 192 190'

x = x1.split()
y = y1.split()

plt.rc('font', size= 6 ) 

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)

plt.grid ( True )

plt.rc('font', size= 5 ) 

plt.show()
```

`x1`, `y1` - входные значения в виде строки, которые преобразуются в списки x,y
[image: Сам график]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому, что строки не интерпретируются как числа, между которыми есть какой-то порядок отношений, а рассматриваются просто как литералы, между которыми расстояние всегда единица. Хотите, чтобы ваши данные трактовались как числа - сделайте их числами:

```py
x = list(map(int, x1.split()))
y = list(map(int, y1.split()))
```

P.S. Картинку сейчас не могу загрузить, к сожалению.
P.P.S. Вместо двух отдельных команд отрисовки:

```py
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Можно сделать тоже самое одной командой:

```py
plt.plot(x,y, '-o')
```